# how to prevent fancybok memory leaks

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks, fancybox

I have image links like:

```
<a className="thumbnail fancybox" href={this.props.imageUrl}>
    <img className="img-responsive" src={this.props.thumbnailUrl} />
</a>
```

and use fancybox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    locked: false
                }
         }
 });
```

what should I do so that using fancybox does not leak too much memory?

I created an image gallery and everytime I click next ( show next page of images ) the memory usage goes up by 10mb!

Comment: what do you exactly mean with `click next ( show next page of images ) ` ? ...it doesn't sound like a fancybox issue then

Comment: I believe modern day browsers have "smart" garbage collection where they don't unload images from memory right away unless they detect that the memory is needed. Are you experiencing system memory problems without the browser fixing it?